# linked list calling inside interrupts

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on a system where I need to achieve (virtually) a real time behavior. I am using non-blocking bare-metal programming and a dsPIC33e microcontroller for this project. Tasks communicate with each other using queues.

I have a low, medium and high priority tasks. High priority task is for example emergency shut down using tactile switch. Low and medium priority task are for communication, sensor reading and there processing respectively. All tasks are checked under RMS (rate monotonic scheduling) and working fine utilizing 60% of processor time.

The question is that I want to call  the low and high priority tasks (linked list of modules) inside hardware timer ISR because the dspic33e processor provides hardware based context switching. But its often said that the interrupt routine should be small as possible and often said that use flags and read in main. If I use these flags and then read these flags in main then i don't achieve a preemption behavior.

can anybody suggest/guide me if it's still good to call the linked lists inside the timer routines?

Comment: I didn't get your problem. Why is using flags not working for you? Why do you want to put them in your main? The wait_for_flag belongs in the event-/cental-loop of your tasks.

Comment: If I use these flags and then read these flags in main then i don't achieve a preemption behavior. In main you are checking cyclically inside while(1) loop so if both of them trigger at the same time you cannot gurantee a medium priority task preempting lower priority task because in that case you are executing tasks by run to completion method.

Comment: [mbed eqeue](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/events/equeue/equeue.h) has exactly a linked list queue of tasks.

Comment: using an embedded RTOS is an overkill (for the tasks mentioned above) because I don't have a large set of tasks.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a linked list?" It should be quick and cheap to add an event to a linked list under interrupt. Maintain separate lists for each level of priority, and then in `main` you can process the highest priority events first.

Comment: "Highest priority is emergency shutdown." If there are no tasks to complete, such as data logging, just remove the power there and then. If there are, then it can't be real time behaviour, and you can't pre-empt the lower priority tasks.

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by "call a linked list?" i mean I have sub-modules  under the medium and low priority task and each sub-module has its separate queue to read its events. "Highest priority is emergency shutdown." This is an error handler function which invokes error handling in medium and low priority task by setting error flags which would be read by corresponding state machines to switch off the actuators. Yes I got your idea that you are talking about a micro scheduler which read event from queue and dispatches/invokes the tasks.

Comment: To achieve preemption behaviour it is doubtful to do it without a scheduler or a minimalist scheduler that just stores essential controller registers. Calling actual tasks in isr context is not safe. It is correct that isr should be small and also should not have wait/delay/sleep and no memory allocations. If the tasks are minimal like read sensor data and return then it may be safe. Instead of modeling as preemptive behaviour it can be producer and consumer tasks. It depends on what is in the tasks.

Comment: An RTOS is not about handling a "large set of tasks" it is about achieving deterministic response - regardless of the number of tasks.  Systems with three or four threads on a microcontroller such as yours is not unusual at all.  And since there are RTOSes for free or very low cost, there is no reason not to use one.  It is not "overkill" at all - trying to implement hard real-time behaviour without one will take you longer and be more error prone, so your arguments against do not withstand scrutiny.

Comment: @Clifford yes I agree with you but not completely. If the hardware manufacturer which in my case provide alternative working "W" registers set under nested ISRs for context saving  (which is normally done by scheduler on contex switch) and provided my tasks return before deadline there is no need of using an OS (at least in my case). See document DS70005158B-page 6 for more details maybe it's more clear than what I am trying to say here.

Comment: @BabarAli Such hardware facilities are available to be exploited by an RTOS.

Comment: @Clifford yes if one for the device is available or somebody is willing to port RTOS for such a device.

Comment: @BabarAli ... Well there is certainly several for dsPIC.  Even if an RTOS does more than you need (and you need not use all of it), implementing even a subset of that functionality reliably is not a trivial task.